# Laravel Wildcard Subdomain for User

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am looking to implement a whitelabel solution to my platform and need to implement wildcard subdomains for or system, the only issue is our system sits on a subdomain its self. So I need to filter out anything that comes to a specific subdomain.

```
// *.website.co.uk
Route::group(['domain' => '{element}.website.co.uk'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function ($element) {
        dd($element);
    });
});

// my.website.co.uk
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getLogin');
Route::post('/', 'PagesController@postLogin');
```

However using the code above I get the error:

> Undefined variable: element

How would I avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way is to exclude 'my' using a pattern. Put this code at the top of your routes file:

```
Route::pattern('element', '(?!^my$)');
```

Alternatively, that can go in the boot() section of your RouteSericeProvider. To give you a working solution, your code becomes the following (you can tidy up later!)

```
Route::pattern('element', '(?!^my$)');

Route::group(['domain' => '{element}.website.co.uk'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getLogin');
    Route::post('/', 'PagesController@postLogin');
});
```

An alternative way is to match the 'my' route before matching the {element} route. However, while many do this I think it might be harder to maintain if the ordering of routes isn't clearly explained in the comments.

Comment: Thank you that worked, I have updated my code as the routes for my.website.co.uk also sit on the same development. The Route::pattern works for the Route::group and then the other routes under still work for the my.website.co.uk domain. Thanks again